# JComboBox as title in titledBorder

Tags: java, jcombobox

I'm using something like this to create a titled border:

```
Border line = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
Border titled = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(line, *someString*);
```

and I'd like to use a JComboBox than a String for a title (replace *someString* with a JComboBox). Can I do this with BorderFactory, something else or do I need to write something custom?

Comment: You can put a JComboBox on your Swing GUI.  You can put the selection of the JComboBox as the title of a titled border.  Why do you want the title to be a JComboBox?

Comment: The combobox would allow the user to change the content inside the border. Right now I have the combobox inside the border as well, but for clarity and ease of use I was trying to make it more clear. Thanks for the response @GilbertLeBlanc.

Comment: Something that's useful to remember when designing a user interface:  lines are bad.  The more lines you have, the harder the organization of the components is for users to see.  Having *very few* lines (one or two) may improve things, but usually, you should use empty space for visual organization.  In this case, the JComboBox probably can be left-aligned above the affected content (along with its JLabel; you do want to support accessibility, right?), possibly with a horizontal separator to the right that extends over the content, if the content is large.